# Freezing panes in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, freeze

I have been trying to figure out if this is possible. So if someone can help Just answer a simple question I would greatly appreciate it.

Is it possible to have the first 2 rows frozen then after scrolling down 50 rows have it replace the frozen row with line 50 and 51?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native formula or feature to do this with, as a cell can't tell which cell is selected/cells are currently in view. You would need to write VBA macro code to change the contents of rows 1 and 2 based on the currently selected cell or currently visible view. So yes it can be done, but not without coding.

You could for instance, use this UDF (https://excel.tips.net/T002302_Displaying_the_Selected_Cells_Address.html) to change the data in row 1 and 2 as a formula, say in A1 `=IF(ROW(INDIRECT(CurrentCell()))>49, A50, "Original A1 data here")`.

Note, this also has some drawbacks. This UDF is volatile and will recalculate all the time, which can be a problem in large workbooks. Also, your undo functionality might be affected (not certain because the UDF isn't writing to the sheet, only reading status of cursor).